# How do I subdue someone?

Tags: battlefield-hardline

I saw footage of someone being arrested by the police.  How do I subdue or arrest an enemy?  Can only the police team do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a blunt weapon (anyone can do it)
2. Hit the enemy from behind (with the blunt weapon) - `F` default key
3. Profit - Interrogate him (press `E` on the downed enemy - it will show all of them on the minimap)

Source and list of Blunt Weapons - http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Blunt_Weapon

Video performing some takedown/interrogation -

(pt-br but you can see the HUD with the buttons)

Answer (score 0):

It seem that police team can only do this.

You do it like a melee kill in other Battlefield game, if you haven't change your key configuration with the "F".

Maybe you should hit him twice (not sure).

Comment: This is not exact